# Retrieving correct item from list with searchview

Tags: android, listview, search, searchview, onitemclicklistener

I have a searchable ListView whose entries are Item objects, which contain a String for their name, and an int for their drawable resource.

Upon searching for an entry and selecting it, the wrong entry is registered in the onItemClick() method since their positions change. How can I reference the correct item after searching?

Below is my attempt; clearly the reference to the "position" parameter is the issue, but I cannot think of a solution to fix this.

```
public class ItemRelicFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Button btn;
    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    String[] names={"Aegis Amulet", "Blink Rune", "Bracer of Undoing", "Cursed Ankh", "Hand of the Gods",
                    "Heavenly Wings", "Horrific Emblem", "Magic Shell", "Meditation Cloak", "Phantom Veil",
                    "Purification Beads", "Shield of Thorns", "Sundering Spear", "Teleport Glyph"};

    int[] images={R.drawable.aegis_amulet, R.drawable.blink_rune, R.drawable.bracer_of_undoing, R.drawable.cursed_ankh, R.drawable.hand_of_the_gods,
            R.drawable.heavenly_wings, R.drawable.horrific_emblem, R.drawable.magic_shell, R.drawable.meditation_cloak, R.drawable.phantom_veil,
            R.drawable.purification_beads, R.drawable.shield_of_thorns, R.drawable.sundering_spear, R.drawable.teleport_glyph};


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

        lv=(ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        sv=(SearchView) myView.findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
        btn=(Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

        //CREATE AND SET ADAPTER TO LISTVIEW
        final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), this.getItems());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //SEARCH
        sv.setQueryHint("Search relics..");
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String txt) {
                return false;
            }
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String txt) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(txt);
                return false;
            }
        });

        //Listener for itemclick on list
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
            {
                int image_id = images[position];
                mListener.onListItemClick(image_id);
                dismiss();
            }
        });
(...) 
} 

private ArrayList<Item> getItems() {

        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Item item;

        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            item = new Item(names[i], images[i]);
            items.add(item);
        }

        return items;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem finally!

My image_id variable in my onItemClick(...) method was pointing to whatever position I physically tapped rather than what item I was selecting.

Here is how I referenced the item:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
            {
                int image_id = adapter.getItem(position).getImage();
                mListener.onListItemClick(image_id);
                dismiss();
            }
```